# How to make a listView with textview and spinner and edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, textview, spinner

How can i create an android listview with row 1: textview + spinner row 2: textview + edittext etc.?

I have to make a form and i make it with xml layout but it's too long and bad for perfomance as the eclipse says.

Thank you!

Comment: `LazyAdapter` is the best option

Comment: can you post an example because i can't find a good one

Comment: `EditTexts` don't work i a `ListView`. If it's a form than use a simple `ScrollView` with the layout inside.

Comment: yes i hava a scrollview but the "activity_form.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance" or i should ignore this error msg?

Comment: first of all you try some thing, then ask for help, there is a lot of samples in google, my be it is not exact as you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

ListView can be used if there is a repetition of same views in every row. This is where you get performance benefits given by adapters' recycling view mechanisms. With every row having different views they cannot be recycled and therefore no point in using the listview there.

So based on what kind of rows you have here are two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Row 1 has textview + spinner, Row 2 has textview + EditText. And this combination repeats for the rest of the rows then you can try this. The xml where you create the layout of individual row for the ListView should be made a LinearLayout having two rows. ListView will create the rest of the rows for you by appending this LinearLayout.

**Solution 2:**

If each row is completely different from other (in terms of views used) then I would suggest using pagination. Divide your form questions into different relevant groups put each group on one page (scrollview). When user answers a set they have to navigate to the next page and so on.

As suggested by @Xaver Kapeller, I'd also suggest not using EditText in a ListView. It is very painful to debug keyboard issues and when the device orientation changes with keyboard open then as well. Instead of EditText ,use TextView which on tapping opens a Dialog box with a EditText. To keep the user interaction minimum.

You can focus the EditText as soon as the dialog open so that keyboard opens and user does not have to tap on the EditText. You can also dismiss the dialog by pressing the imeAction like Done on the soft keyboard or by pressing the hard back button. Dismissing the dialog should trigger a textview.setText("Data entered in the dialog box").